# C Survey Program

Tags: c, file-io

Hi I am fairly new to C and I am trying to make a survey program in C that allows the user to make a choice between different type of questions and stores the survey in a file. My code does not enter while loop and terminates before it. Can someone point out the error please ?

```
 makesurvey()
{
int tfquestions, mcq, shortq,essayq,rankq ;
int i=1;
char *buffer;
printf("\nEnter the number of True/False Questions, Multiple Choice, Short answer , EssayAnswer and rank the   choice questions ");
scanf("%d",&tfquestions);
scanf("%d",&mcq);
scanf("%d",&shortq);
scanf("%d",&essayq);
scanf("%d",&rankq);
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("survey.txt","w");
    while(i=!tfquestions)
    {
            if(fp != NULL)
            {
            fprintf(fp,"Enter The True false question");
            buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(40));
            fscanf(fp,"%c",buffer);
            fclose(fp);
            }

            else
            {
                    printf("Could not open the file");
            }
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: `(i=!tfquestions)` means "assign `not tfquestions` (0 or 1) to `i`"

Comment: `while(i=!tfquestions)` should use `!=`. As is, you set `i` to `!tfquestions`, which results in 0.

Comment: A better answer may be: "increase the warning level of your compiler" :)

Comment: and If i want to write to both console and file i need to use vfprintf right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yout need to usem != not =!

```
fp = fopen("survey.txt","w");
    while(i!=tfquestions)
    {
        if(fp != NULL)
        {
        fprintf(fp,"Enter The True false question");
        buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(40));
        fscanf(fp,"%c",buffer);
        fclose(fp);
        }

        else
        {
                printf("Could not open the file");
        }
i++;
}
```